# Python - Create a list of sets or set of sets?

Tags: python

Need help with a homework exercise for a class I am auditing. The exercise is in association rule mining and I'm extremely stuck at one of the steps to organize the data.

I have a string of data separated by line break (each line represents the items purchased by a customer):

```
rawText = 
"""fruit, bread, butter, soup
   fruit, yogurt, coffee
   whole milk, cream cheese, meat, vegetables"""
```

How can I get this data into a set that looks like this (is this a list of sets?):

```
[{‘fruit’, ‘bread’, ‘butter’, soup’},
 {‘fruit’, ‘yogurt’, ‘coffee’},
 {'whole milk', 'cream cheese', 'meat', 'vegetables'}
]
```

I've tried to break the string by end of line:

```
names_list = [y for y in (x.strip() for x in rawText.splitlines()) if y]
my_set = set()
for i in names_list:
    my_set.add(i)
```

This obviously is not working. Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way?

Comment: If two lines are the same, are you okay with that fact being deleted? Sets don't contain duplicates.

Comment: If one of the responses answers your question please accept it as the answer

Answer (score 7):

To get a list of sets with each set containing the comma-separated words from the given line:

```
names_list = [set(line.strip().split(', ')) for line in raw_text.splitlines()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close but you have two problems:

- You're not splitting the individual items on each line into separate strings
- You're not actually making a set for the items in each line

Given that, this should fix your problem

```
names_list = [set(line.strip().split(',')) for line in raw_text.splitlines()]
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use the `csv` module to deal with line splitting, whitespace and delimiters:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

x = StringIO("""fruit, bread, butter, soup
fruit, yogurt, coffee
whole milk, cream cheese, meat, vegetables""")

with x as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, skipinitialspace=True)
    res = list(map(set, reader))
```

**Result**

```
print(res)

[{'bread', 'butter', 'fruit', 'soup'},
 {'coffee', 'fruit', 'yogurt'},
 {'cream cheese', 'meat', 'vegetables', 'whole milk'}]
```